# Prevent multiple renders when setting multiple setState(s) after each other

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I called multiple setState(s) in a row that causes multiple renders in my react project.

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const [entities, setEntities] = useState([]);

// ...
// somewhere in the code
setEntities(result); // cause render
setIsLoading(false); // cause render
```

How can I prevent multiple renders? (**Instead of merging these states into an object**)

Answer (score 1):

It depends where the `setStates` are called from. Usually they are batched together and trigger one rerender. However, if they are called from some asynchronous code, react is not able to batch them together. You can read more about that behaviour [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/simplifying-state-management-in-react-apps-with-batched-updates/)

If you want to work around that behaviour, you could for example use [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer), that does not suffer from this problem as you only need one update to change data in different places.